# Accessing variables through a Singleton vs through the Activity

Tags: android

I'm re-writing parts of an application that now uses one Activity. Within that Activity is a navigation drawer, which points to different Fragments each containing several nested Fragments which are displayed through a ViewPager.

Previously in order to keep hold of variables that needed to be accessed between Activities, I would use a Singleton. Now this is no longer necessary for my Fragments, as I can use getActivity() to access variables that will be shared between all of these Fragments.

However, when the Activity is paused, I need to store these variables once again in the Singleton so that they can be re-initialized when the Activity is resumed.

So, if indeed the Singleton is necessary for the application to work as it should, is it better that my Fragments access variables through the Activity, or could I just as well use the Singleton to grab/update shared variables?

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), it promise one instance of the object to be accessed by everyone in the system, but it does not define the system, and even so in most implementations system is application, it is not necessary have to be that way.

I suggest to use Activity. It has `saveInstantState` and `resumeInstanteState` as part of it's  life cycle. It beneficial over the Application singleton as it saves the data on disk, and if your process got killed(For example low memory), the next time the user lunch your application, it still be able to restore the state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem that I have with using Bundles to save my Activity's state is that the objects I am sharing between my Fragments are too complex to be Parcelable objects. I use an SQLite database to permanently store things, and one option for me would be to save to SQLite onPause() and read from SQLite onResume(), but this uses too much time when considering that the Activity is destroyed and re-created when the display is rotated.

Comment: @n00bface For long time procedures you should display loading status and do the operation on background thread(I would for all db operations).

Answer (score 0):

> I can use getActivity() to access variables that will be shared between all of these Fragments.

If you want to create `Fragments` which conform to recommended design then don't do this.

A `Fragment` should be self-contained and reusable - it should *never* know what type of `Activity` it is attached to.

Instead you should define a 'Callbacks' interface on each Fragment and have your `Activity` implement it and its methods. You can then continue using your 'singleton' with your `Activity`.